# Creating lookup field in Lightning Compnent

Tags: apex

I want to create a lookup field within a lightning component similar to the one in the picture. However the one in the picture is an action not a lightning component. [image]

The above is the quick action.

Below is the lightning component I currently have. I would like the LX component to have those 3 fields available and also the save button that the quick action has. However, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Component code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
  <aura:attribute name="salescampaignid" type="Id" />   
  <ui:button label="Attach File" press="{!c.openVFPage}" />
  <aura:attribute name="Sales_Campaign" type="Sales_Campaign__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Sales Campaign' }"/>
  <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" value="{!v.Sales_Campaign.Name}"/>  
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post your whole code? I don't think the error comes from the two lines above.

Comment: I have added the component code for my lightning component.

Comment: Is the Sales Campaign object a custom object? If so, you have to use the API Name instead of the label when you declare the type of the attribute.

Comment: Yes it is. I have posted the updated code. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know how to display the field? I thought this code would work

Comment: You have to use the Api Name also in the attribute `sObjectType` instantiation: `<aura:attribute name="Sales_Campaign" type="Sales_Campaign__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Sales_Campaign__c' }"/>`